# How do we determine the number of lines in a text file?

Tags: java, text, io

Hi all I have a local [file](http://qweop.com/test/airports.dat) which looks like this:

```
AAA   Anaa
AAC   EL-ARISH
AAE   Annaba 
AAF   APALACHICOLA MUNI AIRPORT
AAG   ARAPOTI
AAL   Aalborg Airport
AAM   Mala Mala
AAN   Al Ain 
AAQ   Anapa
AAR   Aarhus Tirstrup Airport
AAT   Altay
AAX   Araxa
AAY   Al Ghaydah
...
```

[Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/QandE/answers.html) suggests estimating the number of lines in a file by doing [`java.io.File.length`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)
and dividing the result by 50.

But isn't there a more "solid" way to get the number of lines in a text file (yet without having to pay for the overhead of reading the entire file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit to the estimation algorithm you've got is that it is *very* fast: one `stat(2)` call and then some division. It'll take the same length of time and memory no matter how large or small the file is. But it's also vastly wrong on a huge number of inputs.

Probably the best way to get the specific number is to actually read through the entire file looking for `'\n'` characters. If you read the file in in large binary blocks (think 16384 bytes or a larger power of two) and look for the specific byte you're interested in, it can go at something approaching the disk IO bandwidth.

Comment: Are you saying that comparing with the solution Jonathon suggests, it is faster to read through the entire file looking for `\n` characters

Comment: Jonathon and I gave very similar answers -- except his is allowing Java's libraries to do all the buffering and looking for `'\n'` for you, which is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 8):

Can't you just read the file with a [`FileReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and count the number of lines read?

```
int lines = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
while (br.readLine != null) {
    lines++;
}
```

Comment: But is there a way to do it without having to pay for the overhead of reading the entire file?

Comment: No. How else could you do it? The file is just a stream of bytes, some of which being '\n' which we decide separates lines. Can't get something for nothing.

Comment: Btw I was wondering do you think that reading the entire file searching for the `\n` character would be faster than doing readLines (as sarnold suggested) ?

Comment: This method has overheads. br.readLine creates a String as return value. And Strings are immutable, so there is always a new char array which is created. And of course character encoding is done. This can be avoided by using sarnold solution. (just one buffer array, and no encoding at all)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `BufferedReader` and a `counter` which increment the value 1 for each readLine().