# Number of lines read with Spring Batch ItemReader

Tags: csv, spring-batch

I am using `SpringBatch` to write a csv-file to the database. This works just fine.

I am using a `FlatFileItemReader` and a custom `ItemWriter`. I am using no processor.

The import takes quite some time and on the `UI` you don't see any progress. I implemented a progress bar and got some global properties where i can store some information (like lines to read or current import index).

My question is: How can i get the number of lines from the csv?

Here's my xml:

```
<batch:job id="importPersonsJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="importPersonStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="personItemReader"
                         writer="personItemWriter"
                         commit-interval="5"
                         skip-limit="10">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="java.lang.Throwable"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>             
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="skipListener"/>
                <batch:listener ref="chunkListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="authenticationJobListener"/>
        <batch:listener ref="afterJobListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
 </batch:job>
```

I already tried to use the ItemReadListener Interface, but this isn't possible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to know how many lines where read, it's available in spring batch itself,
take a look at the [StepExecution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html)

The method getReadCount() should give you the number you are looking for.

You need to add a step execution listener to your step in your xml configuration. To do that (copy/pasted from spring documentation):

```
<step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="10"/>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="chunkListener"/>
        </listeners>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```

where "chunkListner" is a bean of yours annotated with a method annotated with @AfterStep to tell spring batch to call it after your step.

you should take a look at the [spring reference for step configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Hope that helps,

Comment: I tried this and it is not exactly what i need. The problem is, that the chunkListener gets called after write! In my ItemWriter i store the number of data read so far. I want a progress bar. That's why i need to know the total amount of lines before my itemWriter writes.

Comment: Well in this case you need to add a step before your processing one whose purpose is just to determine the total number of lines to read.
Spring batch has no way to know what exactly it still needs to process since it switches from one step to the other when the read method returns null.

Comment: Hmm, i read that SpringBatch does something like: read a chunk, process a chunk, read a chunk, process a chunk, ... (repeat this until everything is read) and then write. If it would be possible to intervene just before write, i would be pretty happy. But it is not possible?

Comment: I made a workaround (which is not too nice). I implemented a JobListener. The job Listener has a method beforeJob in which i count the lines of the file. With this workaround i have to run through the file twice, which is not nice, but works for the moment. I wish i could intervene the reader and the writer, that would be so awesome.

Comment: There is no magic in determining how many lines a file have.
You can try the method in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089824/how-do-we-determine-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file) since you are doing a progress bar and they are usually not too critical.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i did. But i am not really happy with it, because i read the file twice.

Comment: Hence the File.length() giving the size in bytes. If the number of bytes per lines is fixed, you can divide that number. Otherwise you can just "guess" it by assuming a fixed length per line. In this case it can give you an estimation. 
Since you are doing a progress bar you could admit some error in your estimation of how much is left.

Comment: just an idea: you can start with a progressbar sized as commit-interval*10 (for example) and when you reach the limit resize progress as commit-interval*20 and so on; it's similar to an indeterminate progress,but show user you are working. Else you can size progress as filesize/1024 and read file pointer.